# (Swift) Unable to decode JSON starting with { "something" : [ {

Tags: json, swift, decoding

Below is a sample of the JSON I am trying to decode:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "Modified": "2022-12-30T22:27:00",
      "Published": "2022-12-23T15:15:00",
      "access": {},
      "assigner": "cve@mitre.org",
      "cvss": null,
      "cwe": "CWE-77",
      "id": "CVE-2022-46642",
      "impact": {},
      "last-modified": "2022-12-30T22:27:00",
      "references": [
        "https://github.com/CyberUnicornIoT/IoTvuln/blob/main/d-link/dir-846/D-Link%20dir-846%20SetAutoUpgradeInfo%20command%20injection%20vulnerability.md",
        "https://www.dlink.com/en/security-bulletin/"
      ],
      "summary": "D-Link DIR-846 A1_FW100A43 was discovered to contain a command injection vulnerability via the auto_upgrade_hour parameter in the SetAutoUpgradeInfo function.",
      "vulnerable_configuration": [
        "cpe:2.3:o:dlink:dir-846_firmware:100a43:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
        "cpe:2.3:h:dlink:dir-846:a1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
      ],
      "vulnerable_configuration_cpe_2_2": [],
      "vulnerable_product": [
        "cpe:2.3:o:dlink:dir-846_firmware:100a43:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
      ]
    },
```

(the JSON file continues with the next `{ "Modified"...`)

I searched for a solution and my code is as follows:

The struct

```
struct CVE : Decodable
{
    var id : String
    var cvss : String? = nil
    var Modified : String
    var summary : String
    
}
struct CVEdata : Decodable
{
    var results : [CVE]
}
```

and the JSON decoding function

```
    func jsonDataRequest () async
    {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://cve.circl.lu/api/query?time_start=30-12-2022,time_end=31-12-2022")
        {
             do
             {
                 let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                 arrCVE = try JSONDecoder().decode([CVEdata].self, from: data)
             }
             catch
            {
                 print(error)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

If the above algorithm is correct, how can I access the data in the **arrCVE** variable? I have tried a for loop for dictionary, but I think the issue is somewhere in the decoding line.
Thank you

Comment: The top-level container of your JSON is _not_ an array, so for start your decoding type should be `CVEData.self` (instead of `[CVEData].self`). Then you can access the list of `CVE` objects via `arrCVE.results`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @Alladinian, I had tried your suggestion before and I got the error: Cannot assign value of type 'CirclCVEs.CVEdata' to type '[CirclCVEs.CVEdata]'.

Comment: Can you show the type declaration of `arrCVE` (hint: it _should_ be `arrCVE: CVEdata`)?

Comment: try this: `let theData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CVEdata.self, from: data)
                arrCVE = theData.results`

Comment: @Alladinian I see your point. I redeclared the variable arrCVE, var arrCVE : CVEdata but the class complains to initialize it. I am not sure what value I should give it.

Comment: You can make it optional `var arrCVE: CVEdata?`

Comment: @Alladinian Thank you very much. My bad. Stuck with easy stuff. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Happy to help. Kalimera from Greece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the top-level container of your JSON is not an array, so for start your decoding type should be `CVEData.self` (instead of `[CVEData].self`).

Then you can access the list of CVE objects via `arrCVE.results`.

Don't forget that `arrCVE` must be redeclared accordingly:

`var arrCVE: CVEdata?`

Comment: Yes, all done! Thank you once again :)